# SQL Server : joining the users table to match the matching column employee number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a query to show the users name from the `users` table to the `tickets` table `requester_id`, `submitter_id`, and `assignee_id` to add a name column behind it like below:

```
  ,t.requester_id
  ,u.name as requester_name
  ,t.submitter_id
  ,u.name as submitter_name
  ,t.assignee_id
  ,u.name as assignee_name
```

If I only do the requester_name and join `join Users as u on t.requester_id = u.ID` it works. But I am trying to do this to three columns.

```
SELECT t.id
 ,t.url
 ,t.external_id
 ,t.type
 ,t.subject
 ,t.description
 ,t.priority
 ,t.status
 ,t.recipient
 ,t.requester_id
 ,u.name as requester_name
 ,t.submitter_id
 ,u.name as submitter_name
 ,t.assignee_id
 ,u.name as assignee_name
 ,t.organization_id
 ,t.group_id
 ,t.collaborator_ids
 ,t.forum_topic_id
 ,t.problem_id
 ,t.has_incidents
 ,t.due_at
 ,t.tags
 ,t.via
 ,t.custom_fields
 ,t.satisfaction_rating
 ,t.sharing_agreement_ids
 ,t.followup_ids
 ,t.ticket_form_id
 ,t.created_at
 ,t.updated_at
 ,t.channel
FROM Tickets as t
join Users as u on t.requester_id = u.ID
join Users as u on t.submitter_id = u.ID
join Users as u on t.assignee_id = u.ID
```

I am trying to add a new row after each requester_id, submitter_id, and assignee_id to show the name after it from the users table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are halfway there, by joining to the Users table three times, but you need to give it a different alias each time:

```
FROM Tickets as t
join Users as ru on t.requester_id = ru.ID
join Users as su on t.submitter_id = su.ID
join Users as au on t.assignee_id = au.ID
```

Then:

```
  ,t.requester_id
  ,ru.name as requester_name
  ,t.submitter_id
  ,su.name as submitter_name
  ,t.assignee_id
  ,au.name as assignee_name
```

Comment: It will if you use `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`.   To keep that from happening, you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.